# Use current item in

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am a bit stuck and I havent been able to find a solution yet. I hope you guys can help.

I have a collectionView

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"
                        x:Name="MediaStreamCollectionView"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged">
```

.....

and inside this I have made a content-view, but I can't figure out how to get the current item, so I can bind that to a content view property.

```
<contentView:FavoriteButton MediaStreamItem="{Binding this}">
```

My ItemList is like this:

```
ObservableCollection<MediaStreamItem> ItemList { get; set; }
```

and my contentview property looks like this

```
        public static readonly BindableProperty MediaProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MediaProperty), typeof(MediaStreamItem), typeof(FavoriteButton), new MediaStreamItem());

    public MediaStreamItem MediaStreamItem
    {
        get => (MediaStreamItem) GetValue(FavoriteButton.MediaProperty);
        set => SetValue(FavoriteButton.MediaProperty, value);
    }
```

It works fine for all the properties on ItemList but not on the current Item-object.

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "." for the current item

```
<contentView:FavoriteButton MediaStreamItem="{Binding .}">
```

Comment: I tried that as well but I get following error message: 

No property, bindable property, or event found for 'MediaStreamItem', or mismatching type between value and property.

Comment: your BindableProperty is named "MediaProperty" not "MediaStreamItem"

Comment: Adding it like this: MediaProperty="{Binding .}", gives me the error: The property 'MediaProperty' was not found in FavoriteButton'

Comment: I think you need to carefully review how your BindableProperty and it's backing property are defined, what you have just doesn't look right to me.

Comment: it works if I bind string types and it also allows me to compile if I change the type to object in the contentview

Comment: FavoriteButton is just contained in your CollectionView template?

Comment: You were right. There was something fishy with my BindableProperties.

In my bindable it should have been BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MediaStreamItem) and I had written BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MediaProperty) - Thanks